# iOS Programming, Save/make audio files from online stream!

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, stream, core-audio

Please help, if you have a bunch of code somewhere, a method or something, I need to make an audio file while the application is streaming the audio, and save the result as file, maybe mp3 or other, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Core Audio Extended Audio File Services to write out audio data that you have access to the samples for:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

I have only used it to write out PCM files, but the documentation suggests that compressed formats are also fine. You have a choice between synchronous and asynchronous writing although there is more setup needed for asynchronous writes.